# Can I add hats to my profile image?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture, winter-bash

Am I allowed to pretend to have earned hats that I didn't, such as the Eureka hat? It's easy enough to manually add it to my image. The question is, is it allowed?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because of course nobody cares.

Comment: @Won't if nobody cares, then why they downvotes?

Comment: @Ooker more important why they upvote my comment?

Comment: @Won't because they care? If they cares to downvote this question then your comment will be  invalid?

Comment: @Ooker but they upvoted my comment, so they care about not caring?  Would you like to go for another round on a stupid comment from over a year ago?  I wouldn't.  You could simply flag the question and ask mods to delete the comments, as they're nothing but noise (and you'd probably get your wish).  I'm sure OP loves getting these notices in his inbox.

Comment: @Won't but I love to twisting around...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It'll be immediately obvious that you don't actually have the hat; the SVG rendering is a) much cleaner, b) slightly delayed. You'd just look sad.

But sure, it is allowed. In Winterbashes Past there were decoy fake hats included in the hat images (CSS sprites were used instead of SVG data URLs) and at least one person edited in one of those decoys into their profile picture, for the lulz. Others edited in a favourite hat to keep it with them after the Winterbash was over, or to be able to wear two hats at once.

Just take into account that actual hat placement allows for the hat to break out of the normal avatar box:

[image: Clever Ninja]

You can't achieve that with just editing your avatar.